# Javascript. Как сделать проверку в калькуляторе на значение?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, прошу помочь с проверкой значений на данный калькулятор. Знаю что можно сделать другой, но как конкретно проверить этот.

Через `do {var c = prompt("Введите действие которое вы хотели бы совершить: +, -, *, /, %");} while (c === "+" || c === "-" || c === "*" || c === "/" || c === "%")` - не работает.

Извиняюсь за такие вопросы, но не хочется бросать не разобравшись.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var res;
        function sum(a, b) {
            res = a + b;
            alert(res); 
        }
        function sub(a, b) {
            res = a - b;
            alert(res);
        }
        function mul(a, b) {
            res = a * b;
            alert(res);
        }
        function div(a, b) {
            res = a / b;
            alert(res);
        }
        function rest(a, b) {
            res = a % b;
            alert(res);
        }       

        do { 
        var a;
        do {
            a = +prompt("Введите первое значение");
        } while( isNaN(a) || a == ' ');


        var c = prompt("Введите действие которое вы хотели бы совершить: +, -, *, /, %"); 


        var b;
        do {
            b = +prompt("Введите второе значение"); 
        } while (isNaN(b) || b == ' ');

        switch (c) {
            case "+":
                {
                    sum(a, b);
                }
                break;
            case "-": 
                {
                    sub(a, b);
                }
                break;
            case "*":
                {
                    mul(a, b);
                }
                break;
            case "/": 
                {
                    div(a, b);
                }
                break;
            case "%": 
                {
                    rest(a, b);
                }
                break;
        }   

        exit = confirm("Продолжить?");
        if (exit) {
            document.write("Вы завершили выполнение.");
        } 
    } while (exit);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "не работает" - а что делает?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function checkThat(c){
  var operatorsArr = {1:"+",2:"-",3:"/",4:"%"};
  var i=0;

  do {
      if (c===operatorsArr[i]) {
         alert("correct") // do something after that
         // as example move to summ function
         return;
      } 
      i++;
  }while(i<operatorsArr.length());
  alert("you are wrong!");
  return;
}
```

Т.е. если блок пройдет по всем значениям словаря operatorsArr, то значит был введен неверный символ.

Comment: Спасибо, логику понял. А где открывать функцию?

Comment: Т.е. открывать ?

Comment: Вы написали функцию для проверки значения "с", но для того чтобы эта проверка сработала функция должна открывается в коде или возможна я что то не правильно понимаю?

Comment: `var c = prompt("Введите действие которое вы хотели бы совершить: +, -, *, /, %");` Вот после этой строки можно вызвать данную функцию, чтобы проверить ввод с промта. Т.е. написать `checkThat(c);` (предварительно добавив саму функцию в область видимости т.е. хоть где то ее определить =) )

Comment: сделав ключами объекта сами значения операторов, а не цифры, можно было бы вообще без цикла обойтись